# Compile Ada for ARM architecture

Tags: compiler-construction, embedded, ada

Does anyone know of a compiler that will compile Ada on ARM (for Linux)? Preferably it would compile for at least Ada 2005.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debian 6.0 (squeeze) contains GCC 4.4 with GNAT Ada (`apt-get install gnat`) and can be obtained for `armel` (ARM EABI). GCC 4.4 supports Ada 2005.

Comment: @Jeff After you have installed `gnat` you should be able to do `man gcc` and search for `ARM` to find the options you will want to use.

Comment: Yeah, I knew gcc would do it, didn't know it supports 2005. Seems to be the best (only?) option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:
http://www.arm.com/community/partners/display_product/rw/ProductId/5620/

Comment: Found that through Google too. Unfortunately, it only compiles for ARM on Nucleus OS--not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've only heard of ARM Android target. Check [this](http://www.dragonlace.net/) for more details.